# Proof of Cavalieri's Principle with the help of Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,A,\mu )$ is a measure space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a nonnegative $A$-measurable function, then the function $t\mapsto \mu(\left \{ f>t \right \})$ is also measurable and I want to show that $\int _{X}f\,d\mu=\int _{\mathbb R^{+}}\mu(\left \{ f>t \right \})\,dL^{1}(t)$; here $\left \{ f>t \right \}$ is the set  $\left \{ x;f(x)>t \right \}$ and $L^{1}$ is the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure. I want to prove this theorem by using Fubini's theorem; I have already proved it without using Fubini's theorem but I don't know how to prove it with the help of Fubini's theorem. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use Fubini on $X\times \mathbb{R}_+$ with indicator function $(x,t)\mapsto \mathbf{1}_{\{f(x)>t\}}$.

Comment: How did you prove it without Fubini's theorem?  This does not seem to be research level.